# on-contextmenu function is not working on <iron-image> in polymer?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, polymer

I have to disable the right click on a image for a image restriction and i am using `on-contextmenu="return false;` and  `on-contextmenu="return disableRightClick" on a  but its not working for me tell me how to fix this problem?

```js
disableRightClick : function(event) {
    alert("Sorry, right click is not allowed !!"); 
  return false; 
}
```

```html
<div class='dashboard-prod-right' id='sellerProduct' style='width:100%;' on-click="setSelProduct" >
<div>
  <iron-image class="defaultImageURL" src="[[product.sellerProductSetDto.0.setImageURLList.0.imageURL]]" on-contextmenu="return disableRightClick"
    style="width:calc(100% - 10px);height:170px!important;cursor:pointer;background-color: white;"class="sized" sizing="contain" placeholder="/img/placeholder.jpg"  preload fade >
  </iron-image>
</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it, just remove `return` from `on-contextmenu="return disableRightClick"` (in Polymer you have to bind it to a function, not a statement).

```
<iron-image ... on-contextmenu="disableRightClick">
```

Comment: it is working but sir i have to disable the rightClick not show any alert how to do this?

Comment: Just remove the alert and leave there the `return false` and it will not show the context menu. Is that what you want?

Comment: sir i have to remove the alert but same result show right click option show again?